# List parsing , in place looping, hex conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7

First day with python and new coder here, would very much appreciate some help, i have a log file

```
End:   1398789531:    934328  6 V       160.0.0.9:18299
End:   1398789535:    938994  6 V       160.0.0.7:14586
End:   1398789540:    944668  6 V       160.0.0.9:36690
```

Id like to extract the IP address, strip the port and the convert the IP to hex for further processing, so far I only have this working

```
with open('myfile') as infile:
for line in infile:
    print(line.split()[5])
```

result =

```
160.0.0.9:18299
160.0.0.7:14586
160.0.0.9:36690
```

can anyone show me an elegant solution for striping the port off the end and then converting these to hex please ..

cheers

Comment: I downvoted your question because it shows no research effort, you ask for code that is a solution to a problem you have not yet run into

Comment: you can try to find the position of ":" and then use the string from 0 to position to get the ip address. For converting to string, you'll have to conver individual parts of the ip octets to hex.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the code that was failing to run as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is myfile that has in it:

```
End:   1398789531:    934328  6 V       160.0.0.9:18299
End:   1398789535:    938994  6 V       160.0.0.7:14586
End:   1398789540:    944668  6 V       160.0.0.9:36690
```

the next piece of code:

```
with open("myfile", 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    ip_addr_hex = map(hex, map(int, list(line.split()[-1].split(':')[0].split('.'))))
    print(ip_addr_hex)
```

will produce the output bellow, which is the hex of each of the number of the IPs:

```
['0xa0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x9']
['0xa0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x7']
['0xa0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x9']
```

The following code:

```
with open("myfile", 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    ip_addr_hex = '.'.join(map(hex, map(int, list(line.split()[-1].split(':')[0].split('.')))))
    print(ip_addr_hex)
```

will produce this output:

```
 0xa0.0x0.0x0.0x9
 0xa0.0x0.0x0.0x7
 0xa0.0x0.0x0.0x9
```

You choose the code depending of the desired output.
What you have to take from here is the "looping in place" which makes use of the "map" function. General use is map(func, list).

You have to read the statement from **inside -> out**. First, line.split[-1] captures the last element(-1) of the line. Next,    .split(':')[0] captures the first element of a string that is delimited by ':', this is your IP. Third, .split('.') , divides the element of the IP. list () transform the entire string into a list so you can apply map function on each of the elements all at once which are string at this point. In this case the first function that is applied is map(int, list(...)). This transforms all those strings in integers. Now, you have a list of integers upon you wich apply the map function again map(hex,....) to transform all those integers in hex values. Does it makes sense? The point to get from here is that you have to read the entire statement from inside -> out.

Comment: hi imui, Im trying to really understand this line - 'ip_addr_hex = '.'.join(map(hex, map(int, list(line.split()[-1].split(':')[0].split('.')))))' , so the first map takes hex as a funtion and another map as the sequence....If you could explain that futher that would be great ,  i have been reading about the map function butI don't fully understand how you have used 2 ....

Comment: @biscuitlove I appended more details to my initial answer. See above.Change the title of your post to a more generic python issue so people can refer to it easily.

Comment: ok , many thanks for your response this makes sense now, I was in San Jose the other week , I would have bought you a beer :)

Comment: @biscuitlove: next time...:) again, please change the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('myfile') as infile:
for line in infile:
    ip = line.split()[5].split(':')[0].split('.')
    hex = ''
    for i in ip:
       hex += hex(int(i))
    print hex
```

Comment: Thanks , I didn't realise you could set delimiters with split ...awesome